# Remove a disk from RAID 1 array or convert from RAID1 to RAID0

Tags: raid, raid-1, raid-0

I've a dedicated server running a RAID1 array of 2 disks of 1TB.
I can't install a new operating system but I can only bootstrap a new one with the predefined configuration.

I really don't need the mirroring, instead I need more IO speed (expecially writing).

This is my actual configuration:

```
sda               8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk  
├─sda1            8:1    0     4G  0 part  
│ └─md1           9:1    0     4G  0 raid1 /
├─sda2            8:2    0     2G  0 part  [SWAP]
└─sda3            8:3    0 925.5G  0 part  
  └─md3           9:3    0 925.5G  0 raid1 
    ├─vg00-usr  253:0    0    36G  0 lvm   /usr
    ├─vg00-var  253:1    0    35G  0 lvm   /var
    ├─vg00-home 253:2    0     3G  0 lvm   /home
    └─vg00-data 253:3    0   850G  0 lvm   /data
sdb               8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk  
├─sdb1            8:17   0     4G  0 part  
│ └─md1           9:1    0     4G  0 raid1 /
├─sdb2            8:18   0     2G  0 part  [SWAP]
└─sdb3            8:19   0 925.5G  0 part  
  └─md3           9:3    0 925.5G  0 raid1 
    ├─vg00-usr  253:0    0    36G  0 lvm   /usr
    ├─vg00-var  253:1    0    35G  0 lvm   /var
    ├─vg00-home 253:2    0     3G  0 lvm   /home
    └─vg00-data 253:3    0   850G  0 lvm   /data
```

What can I do?
Can I remove the vg00-data lvm an use the free space (850Gb) as 2 independent ext4 partitions?

Or I can switch from RAID 1 to RAID 0 without data loss? (I need to keep the os, I can loose vg00-data).

Answer (score 0):

Anything you do here will incur risk - If you are working remotely  the risk here is super high. Make sure you have a full backup first.

The correct solution is to rebuild your system with software RAID0 to take advantage of striping.

You might be able to  in essence, convert your raid1 into something close to a raw disk by degrading the array and removing the second disk.  You can then reinitialise the second disk and make it a second physical volume for vg00 and then converting the existing llogical volumes to striped volumes.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/348873/convert-a-single-drive-lvm-volume-to-a-striped-volume-across-3-drives#349041 appears to be a convoluted hack to convert a regular volume to a striped one.